# MongoDB Java : store and increment 2x2 Matrix

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

I am building a model that allows users to configure a table in mongodb and increment values based on row, column name. Below is my model:

```
public Class Matrix{
    String id;
    List<String> columns;
    List<String> rows;
    long[][] values;
}
```

When a new object is saved, I populate the Matrix with all 0's,

```
object.setValues(new long[object.getRows().size()][object.getColumns().size()]);
```

My use case is, I need to increment the corresponding number when a word for row and column is encountered. Labels for columns and rows are stored in corresponding lists.  So, I am trying to do something like this:

```
matrix.update(<get the index of both row and column value and update values[][] accordingly>)
```

However, I can't seem to find/form a query that will do both (i.e. return index and update the value). Another approach would be to get the document by id and increment it in Java, but that would need two db calls.

Is there any alternate way to do this? Should I change my model?

Comment: How are you storing the matrix? Can you share your structure ?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235249/increment-matrix-structure-in-mongodb) has answers suggesting posible matrices encodings for mongodb.

Comment: @Veeram class I shared above, is the example of model only, it will go straight into mongodb. @cjungel I had a look at that example already, I guess it will be difficult to determine the index as we can't do `indexOf`kinda query in mongo update.